# extracting technical keywords from a text document

Tags: nltk, glossary, keyword-search, pos-tagger

Re-written:

I have a corpus of computer science related documents. I want to extract domain specific keywords. for example JAVA, C#, HTML, OOP, UML, Unity, etc. I was looking for a source similar to Oxford dictionary for computing, however their API is not up and running yet. I have also tried Webopedia for computer science terms but that one is not as inclusive and updated ( e.g. it doesn’t include some words in my documents such as F#)  or in case of Wikipedia all terms are not listed all together. Is there a more inclusive source or appropriate approach to extract those keywords?  I am using Python with NLTK . For example, tf-idf wasn’t helpful because some domain specific words are common almost in all documents so those words don’t get a high rating. I think it would be helpful if I could use the POS-tagging but I’m not sure which option would be the best for my application. Take the string below as an example:

“Expert level capabilities in JavaScript, JSON, and AJAX, and a deep knowledge of JavaScript frameworks such as JQuery
“
Here I want to extract these words : [‘JavaScript’, ‘JSON’, ‘AJAX’, ‘Frameworks’, ‘JQuery’] but when I search for nouns using POS-tagging of NLTK, I get ‘level’, ‘capability’, ‘knowledge’ … as well.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: recruitment database?

Comment: "all the concepts and skills necessary" - How are D3, three.js, or F# "necessary"?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is being down voted. @user2357112 as you might know, knowing a language such as F# , APIs and libraries are listed as skills in job postings all the time so I am not sure what confuses you in case of my question.

Comment: @Mina After the rewrite your question is much clearer, and I have voted for a re-open. If I recall correctly there must be four other votes before it actually is reopened.

Comment: Voted to reopen. Dunno how common it is for questions to reach the reopen threshold or get answers after a reopen, but the new version of the question is much clearer.

Comment: @user2357112 awesome! Hopefully it will.

Comment: @MitchWheat: I wrote a new version of my question to clarify the problem by explain the specific programming question I have. I hope it is clarifies the question now.

Comment: I understand it was re-written, but what exactly is your question? (I read it twice, and I can't see what you are asking).

Comment: @noloader: I had an example:   As an example take this string: “Expert level capabilities in JavaScript, JSON, and AJAX, and a deep knowledge of JavaScript frameworks such as JQuery “ Here I want to extract these words : [‘JavaScript’, ‘JSON’, ‘AJAX’, ‘Frameworks’, ‘JQuery’] How can I do that? I have strings similar to this example with keywords related to software engineering and programming.  How can I extract those words? Isn't it clear from my question? I am really surprised that even with the example it is not clear! It is a programming question so how is it off topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you download the StackOverflow data dumps and write a program to filter the tags?

They just have been released on archive.org, see [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/)

Of course, it would not include all terms and there would be some false positives, but I assume this is about as close as you will get.

Comment: This is  a very good idea, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I gave it a try and it is actually very very very helpful!Thanksss

Comment: @Mina, could you share the list of tags from stackoverflow you parsed?